# Does calling `cache` on a spark dataframe eliminate the need for future calls to Hive/HDFS?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

We have a spark application that reads data using spark SQL from HMS tables built on parquet files stored in HDFS. The spark application is running on a seperate hadoop environment. We use delegation tokens to allow the spark application to authenticate to Kerberized HMS/HDFS. We cannot and must not use keytabs to authenticate the spark application directly.
Because delegation tokens expire, after certain period of time our spark application will no longer be able to authenticate and will fail if it has not completed within the timeframe during which the token is valid.
My question is this.

If I call .cache or .persist on the source dataframe against which all subsequent operations are executed, my understanding is that this will cause spark to store all the data in memory.  If all the data is in memory, it should not need to make subsequent calls to read leaf files in HDFS and the authentication error could be avoided. Not that the spark application has its own local file system, it is not using the remote HDFS source as its default fs.

Is this assumption about the behavior of .cache or .persist correct, or is the only solution to rewrite the data to intermediate storage?

Answer (score 0):

Solve Kerberos issue, instead of adding work arounds. I'm not sure how you are using the kerberos principal, but I will point out that the [documentation maintains a solution for this issue](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/security.html#kerberos):

> Long-Running
>
> Applications Long-running applications may run into
> issues if their run time exceeds the maximum delegation token lifetime
> configured in services it needs to access.
>
> This feature is not available everywhere. In particular, it’s only
> implemented on YARN and Kubernetes (both client and cluster modes),
> and on Mesos when using client mode.
>
> Spark supports automatically creating new tokens for these
> applications. There are two ways to enable this functionality.
>
> Using a Keytab
>
> By providing Spark with a principal and keytab (e.g.
> using spark-submit with --principal and --keytab parameters), the
> application will maintain a valid Kerberos login that can be used to
> retrieve delegation tokens indefinitely.
>
> Note that when using a keytab in cluster mode, it will be copied over
> to the machine running the Spark driver. In the case of YARN, this
> means using HDFS as a staging area for the keytab, so it’s strongly
> recommended that both YARN and HDFS be secured with encryption, at
> least.

I would also point out that caching will reduce visits to HDFS but may still require reads from HDFS if there isn't sufficient space in memory.  If you don't solve the Kerberos issue because of [reasons]. You may wish to instead [use checkpoints](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#checkpointing). They are slower than caching, but are made specifically to help [long running process that sometimes fail] get over that hurdle of expensive recalculation, but they do require disk to be written to. This will remove any need to revisit the original HDFS cluster.  Typically they're used in Streaming to remove data lineage, but they also have their place in expensive long running spark applications.  (You also need to manage their cleanup.)

[How to recover with a checkpoint file.](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/content/spark-sql-checkpointing.html)

Comment: I should be more explicit.

Comment: did this answer help you? Could you clarify what I missed?

Comment: The question was if the data is stored in memory, why would I need to go back to HDFS?

Comment: If it fits in memory it won't.  If you call cache on enough data frames it won't fit in memory.  Spark also needs space for working data. Basically there isn't a guarantee, and you should have a plan for when it doesn't.